# I'm using Nodemailer (Node js) to send Email via Gmail but i'm getting error

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I want to send email via Gmail or other email provider like office 365 using Nodemailer as my module Node.js.

I wanna ask also if there's a proxy or firewall setting to disable so that I can send email using gmail or office 365.

Or maybe there is something wrong with my code ?

const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

function sendEmail(to, subject, html){

```
nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'philip@gmail.com',
      pass: 'sercretpass'
    }
});
```

let mailOptions = {
            from: '"Admin" ',
            to: to,
            subject: subject,
            html: html 
        };

```
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Error', error);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Success', info);
        }
    });
});
```

}

module.exports.sendEmail = sendEmail;

MY ERROR :

Error { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.203.108:465
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1121:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '74.125.203.108',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN' }

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to telnet to smtp.gmail.com from the machine on port 465 ?
Also try with Port 587, with 587, you should see some other error as it works on STARTTLS.

Comment: The same error I got but port is 587 and ip is different,.

Comment: I also successfully ping the ip address I got from the host. 
I'm getting loss now I don't know if I need to check proxy or firewall setting.

Comment: have you tried Enabling less secure apps to access  your Gmail

Answer (score 0):

**TESTED WORKING ON GMAIL 2022 March**

1. STEP 1- Enable the "Less Secure App Access" from  Security Page of the Google Account
   . Google says It's no longer supported but turn On
   the feature anyway.
2. STEP 2-Turn Off the google CAPTCHA.
3. STTEP 3- Configuring Port And HOST
   **Do not use google as the host.Refer the following.

> host: "smtp.gmail.com"

if port 587 is not working, try port 465. Make sure to make `secure:true` for port 465

```
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.gmail.com",  
            port: 465,      
            secure: true,      
            auth: {
              user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
              pass: 'password', 
            },
            // enable below only if u are running on local host
            tls: { rejectUnauthorized: true }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

try another network connect like wifi or something else

Answer (score -1):

I always used nodemailer for sending emails, suddenly I started having the above error. So I thought what was new on the computer and found that the antivirus was causing the problem. So disabling the antivirus and windows firewall is a good start to solve the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31744412)